# Custom menus not showing in Menu Settings in WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress, macos, custom-wordpress-pages

I'm a WordPress beginner working on a local server I set up with MAMP. I created the style, index, footer, header and functions docs, and PHP assembled everything with no problems. The website published all my files as expected. Then I tried to add custom menus to the appearance panel / menus in the admin dashboard, but they wouldn't show up.

Here's a snapshot of my folder hierarchy:

[image: shot of folder hierarchy]

And here's a screenshot of the admin page:

[image]

And this is all the code in my functions.php file so far:

```
<?php

function macsc_script_enqueue() {
    wp_enqueue_style('customstyle', get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/macsc.css', array(), '1.0.0', 'all');
    wp_enqueue_script('customjs', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/macsc.js', array(), '1.0.0', true);
}

add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'macsc_script_enqueue');

function register_my_menus() {
  register_nav_menus(
    array(
      'header-menu' => __( 'Header Menu' ),
      'extra-menu' => __( 'Extra Menu' )
    )
  );
}
add_action( 'init', 'register_my_menus' );
```

I've read several stack overflow threads and consulted the WordPress Codex support documentation. The register_my_menus function was a direct copy and paste from the WordPress doc. As far as I can tell, I'm doing everything correctly (obviously not, of course).

One thing that seems odd to me is that there were already tabs for "widgets," "menus" and "header" in the Appearance panel. Considering this is a custom theme that started with an empty folder, I'm not sure why those are there at all.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typically menus are registered on the [`after_setup_theme`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/after_setup_theme) hook. I'd try using that instead of `init`.

Also you don't need to register custom widgets or widget area support for the Widgets menu to show up, there's a lot that WordPress introduces in the core, regardless of your theme or active plugins.

And on second glance, it appears the TwentySeventeen theme is active, considering the `Top Menu` and `Social Links Menu` are the default menus in the TwentySeventeen (default) theme.

From **TwentySeventeen/functions.php**:

```
register_nav_menus( array(
    'top'    => __( 'Top Menu', 'twentyseventeen' ),
    'social' => __( 'Social Links Menu', 'twentyseventeen' ),
) );
```

Go to Appearance > Themes and make sure your custom theme is activated.

Comment: I replaced `init` with `after_setup_theme` and still no joy. Thanks though.

Comment: Looking at the Screenshot again, are you sure you activated your theme? `Top Menu` and `Social Links Menu` are the default menus in the TwentySeventeen theme. Go to Appearance > Themes and make sure your custom theme is activated

Answer (score 0):

I always register the menu in this way:

```
if ( !function_exists( 'theme_setup' ) ) {
    function theme_setup() {
        /*
         * Some settings functions
         */
        register_nav_menus(
            array(
                'header-menu' => __( 'Header Menu', 'domain' ),
                'extra-menu'  => __( 'Extra Menu', 'domain' )
            )
        );
    }
}
add_action( 'after_setup_theme', 'theme_setup' );
```

Comment: I replaced the last block of code in my example with this snippet and still no change. Thanks anyway.